# Copy file from Remote Desktop (RDP) to Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a requirement to copy a file from C: Drive of a remote desktop (RDP) to Azure blob storage.
The RDP server is accessible only through the Jump box.

How can I get the file that is on the RDP to Azure Storage, which linked service can I use to create the connection.

Is there a straight forward way in Azure to do this or some workaround needs to be done for this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you specifically looking for blob storage or will a file share work?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: The file which is in RDP is in csv format so I want to store it in Blob storage. But let me know what do you mean by file share ?

Comment: In a storage account, you can have containers, file shares, tables, and queues. If you are happy with the file being in a file share, you can use my answer.

Comment: Uploading to Azure blob storage would require installing `az` on the virtual machine which is an extra step.

Answer (score 0):

**Upload the file to a file share**

The easiest way would be to mount a file share directly to your machine.
You can find detailed instructions on how to do so:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-quick-create-use-windows

To sum the article up, the instructions are:

1. In the Azure portal, create a file share in the storage account.
2. From the storage account, click *connect*
3. A pane will pop up on the right. Choose a drive letter which is unused on your VM and then copy the command.
4. Paste the command in a Powershell terminal in the virtual machine.

Once the file share is mounted, you can simply copy your file to the drive and it will be uploaded to Azure.

---

**Upload the file to Blob Storage**

You would have to install the Azure CLI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-cli

and then use the `az copy` command.

Comment: But I want to create a pipeline that will do copying of the file from RDP to the Azure storage. This process I will have to do it manually. How can I do it from Azure Data Factory. I am asking something similar to Copy from blob to blob. Also the RDP is an ON-PREM machine and not a VM in azure, so in this case will your answer work ?